# Wildcards in branch names specification in "git merge"

Tags: git, merge

Is it possible to somehow use wildcards when specifying branch names in "git merge"?

For example, if I have:

```
sbos@malta:~/tmp/texterra$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/share/branch1
  origin/share/branch2
  origin/share/another-branch
```

Can I do:

```
git merge origin/share/*
```

to merge with branch1, branch2 and another-branch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can use wildcards directly in that way, but you could use `git for-each-ref` to match branch names.  For example, look at the output of:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/remotes/origin/share/*bran*
```

(That's deliberately more than you need in the pattern, so that I could demonstrate that wildcards work.  You could just do `refs/remotes/origin/share/` instead.)

So, as one command you could do:

```
git merge $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/remotes/origin/share/)
```

... to do an octopus merge from all of those branches.

To be honest, though, I'm finding it hard to think of a situation where I wouldn't much prefer to do:

```
git merge origin/share/branch1
git merge origin/share/branch2
git merge origin/share/another-branch
```

... or perhaps if there are *lots* of branches:

```
for c in $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/remotes/origin/share/)
do
    git merge $c || break
done
```

Answer (score 3):

`git branch -r | grep "share" | xargs git merge` ?

Comment: The simpliest, one-line solution!